# How does integer multiplication result in a fraction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> In an answer to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3502266/how-do-i-solve-the-quintic-n5-m4n-fracp2m-0-for-n/3533818#3533818), Yuri Negometyanov has some equations that I do not follow completely and he has not answered my comment-questions about them.

**2.**

At the same time, $A^2B^2 = (C-k)^2(C^2-(C-k)^2),$ 
with the least value at $k=1.$

Then 
$$A^4 B^4 = (C-1)^4(2C-1)^2 = (C-1)^4 (4C^2-4C+1),$$

$$P^4 = A^4B^4C^4 = \dfrac1{256}(4C^2-4C)^4(4C^2-4C+1)\\[4pt] 
> \dfrac1{256}\Big(4C^2-4C\Big)^5
= \dfrac1{256}\Big((2C-1)^2-1\Big)^5,$$
$$C < \dfrac12\left(\sqrt{(4P)^{^4/_5}+1\ }\ + 1\right).\tag2$$

*Example:* $A=35, B=12, C=37, P=15540, \dfrac12\left(\sqrt{62160^{0.8}+1}+1\right)\approx41.843.$

> Where and how does $\frac{1}{256}$ enter the picture?   And how does it turn into $\frac{1}{2}$ later?

Comment: Because $\frac1{256}(4)^4=1$. It doesn't "turn into $1/2$" - this fraction results from the $2$ in front of $2C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The ${1\over 256}$ and the ${1\over 2}$ are unrelated.**

---

Re: your first question, a couple algebra steps are occurring at once.

- First, we go from $$A^4B^4=(C-1)^4(4C^2-4C+1)$$ to $$A^4B^4C^4=C^4(C-1)^4(4C^2-4C+1),$$ just by multiplying both sides by $C^4$.
- Now we work on the "$C^4(C-1)^4$" part of the right hand side. Specifically, we first have $$C^4(C-1)^4=(C(C-1))^4$$ by combining like powers, and then $$=(C^2-C)^4$$ by expanding.
- Finally, we multiply by $4^4\over 4^4$: we have $$(C^2-C)^4={4^4\over 4^4}(C^2-C)^4={(4(C^2-C))^4\over 4^4}={(4C^2-4C)^4\over 256}$$ (where the second $=$ again involves combining like powers).

---

Re: your second question, note the "$2C$" on the right hand side of the inequality $$P^4>\dfrac1{256}\Big((2C-1)^2-1\Big)^5$$ (which is what we're left at just before getting the final inequality). In order to get an inequality with "$C$" on its own we're going to need to divide both sides of some equation by $2$ at some point.